# Gitkraken error when pull with git-lfs on macOS

Tags: git, macos, path, git-lfs, gitkraken

I have an error during the LFS pull with Gitkraken on macOS. I get the following error message:

> Error on LFS Pull git: 'lfs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. The most similar command is log

In the Gitkraken documentation ([here](https://support.gitkraken.com/git-workflows-and-extensions/intro-and-requirements/#git-lfs-requirements)) we find the following explanation:

> Note: If GitKraken still cannot find Git or Git LFS, the terminal or CMD may be using a different path than the system or user path. For example, on OSX applications launched from the GUI have a different path than those launched from the terminal.

To check this, we can do the following command: `which git-lfs` and `which git`

Indeed, I get the following result:

```
which git     /usr/bin/git \
which git-lfs /opt/homebrew/bin/git-lfs
```

Then, the documentation says that you have to add an environment variable in the path, the example is given for windows, but I can't reproduce the equivalent for macOS

In my .zshrc I have this: `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

I tried it with: `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin/git-lfs:$PATH` but it doesn't work

It's possible that the error is absolutely obvious but I don't know much about environment variables etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem.

There was no PATH problem so I left the original line in .zshrc

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

You have to go to the project with a terminal and do the following command

```
git lfs install
```

the answer will be

> Updated git hooks. 
> Git LFS initialized.

Then do `CMD + R` in Gitkraken. Now the LFS icon will be visible and the pull will work

Comment: Life saver  - Gitkraken should make it clear on their support page about where you need to do this command - i.e. in their guide, against the project with the in-built terminal. This page is okay - https://help.gitkraken.com/gitkraken-client/git-lfs/#git-lfs-requirements , but lacks this important info!

Answer (score 1):

Your `PATH` setting needs to refer only to directories, not to files.  So if the `git-lfs` binary is in `/opt/homebrew/bin`, then you'd want to do this:

```
$ export PATH="$HOME/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
```

Note that that may or may not have an effect on graphical programs, but should if the program is launched from the command line.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help, it seems logical and I modified my path as you indicate, however I always have the error of Gitkraken when I try to pull the LFS files.